# Yarn Run Build Fails , TypeError: _module.default.createRequireFromPath is not a function

Tags: react-native, yarnpkg

When I run yarn run build it fails with below error, I'm new to this env how should I debug this error.

```
yarn run build
yarn run v1.22.10
warning ../../../package.json: No license field
$ yarn clean && yarn prep && yarn bundle && yarn combine-ivm-loc-files
warning ../../../package.json: No license field
$ rimraf Resources && rimraf ItemsViewMobileStrings
warning ../../../package.json: No license field
$ node mkdirp.js Resources
warning ../../../package.json: No license field
$ haul bundle --entry-file index.mobile.js --platform android --minify true --dev false --bundle-output Resources/main.android.bundle --assets-dest Resources
error ▶︎ TypeError: _module.default.createRequireFromPath is not a function
```

Comment: Looks like some export problem. Could you please share how `createRequireFromPath` is exported from the module?

Answer (score 0):

You should have something like this

```
"license": "ISC",
```

in your package.json file.